# Chrome and Firefox extension API have different behaviours for same api

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, cookies, browser-extension

I'm developing a browser extension and I want to cover both Chrome and Firefox.
The extension itself has an accompanying webapp and I wanted to use the session cookies stored in the browser once the user logins via the webapp.
This is working fine for chrome, via the following api.

```js
chrome.cookies.get({ url: 'http://localhost:3000', name: 'cookie-name' }).then((cookie) => {
    return cookie.value;
});
```

Nevertheless, even though Mozilla [claims to have a similar cookies api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Work_with_the_Cookies_API) (using `browser` instead of `chrome`), this is failing to find the cookie  (cannot access value of null)

```js
browser.cookies.get({ url: 'http://localhost:3000', name: 'cookie-name' }).then((cookie) => {
    return cookie.value;
});
```

The manifest looks exactely the same, and from what I checked both should work (using v3).
This code is being executed in the `popup.js` loaded via script tag in `popup.html`.

I really don't know what's happening here, could any particular cookie header that could be treated differently by the engines?

Thanks

Comment: is the cookie a secure cookie? read what you can/can't do [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies) - perhaps firefox is more restrictive than chrum

Comment: Hey! No, it isn't.. I've tried with pretty much any combination (httpOnly, secure, sameSite)